# How to run the predicted probabilities (or average marginal effects) for individuals fixed effects in panel data using R?

Tags: r, panel-data, emmeans, marginal-effects

These are three different ways to run an individual fixed effect method which gives more or less the same results (see below). My main question is how to get predictive probabilities or average marginal effects using the second model (`model_plm`) or the third model(`model_felm`). I know how to do it using the first model (`model_lm`) and show an example below using `ggeffects`, but that only works when i have a small sample.

As i have over a million individual, my model only works using `model_plm` and `model_felm`. If i use `model_lm`, it takes a lot of time to run with one million individuals since they are controlled for in the model. I also get the following error: `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)`. I checked many threads on StackOverflow to work around that error but nothing seems to solve it.

I was wondering whether there is an efficient way to work around this issue. My main interest is to extract the predicted probabilities of the interaction `residence*union`. I usually extract predictive probabilities or average marginal effects using one of these packages: `ggeffects`,`emmeans` or `margins`.

```
library(lfe)
library(plm)
library(ggeffects)
data("Males")  

model_lm = lm(wage ~ exper + residence+health + residence*union +factor(nr)-1, data=Males)
model_plm = plm(wage ~ exper + residence + health + residence*union,model = "within", index=c("nr", "year"), data=Males)
model_felm = felm(wage ~ exper + residence + health + residence*union | nr, data= Males)

pred_ggeffects <- ggpredict(model_lm, c("residence","union"), 
                    vcov.fun = "vcovCL", 
                    vcov.type = "HC1",
                    vcov.args = list(cluster = Males$nr))
```

Comment: There is a new `nuisance` argument in `emmeans::ref_grid` that may help. Just add `nuisance = "nr"` to the call, and hope that gets passed to `emmeans`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried it, but it does not work with `model_plm` or `model_felm` which are the models that I am trying to run. Your suggestion works with `model_lm`, but my analysis cannot run using the base `lm` function since there are over a million individual controlled for in the model

Comment: Well, then I guess there is not a remedy. The nuisance provision pre-averages over the specified factor(s) but that cannot be done if the model is not additive. Seems to me you should be modeling `nr` as a random effect anyway; it's hard to imagine that you have a specific interest in the effects of a million individuals.

Comment: Including person-level fixed effects adjusts for all stable individual characteristics, such as time-invariant aspects of intelligence, preferences, and work habits. I might be wrong, but from what I know, the RE cannot account (the same way as FE does) for these time-invarying characteristics

Comment: True, not in the same way; but the difference is the scope of the statistical inference. Is your goal to estimate the average over all individuals, or the mean response for a particular set of identified individuals? If the latter, (treating them as fixed effects), you may not make a statistical inference outside of that set of individuals -- and if you do, you are under-representing the error in your estimates.

Comment: I am analyzing how self-perceived health changed between people of different social classes before and after the 2008 financial crisis. Person-level fixed effect is used extensively in the field of health because there are various unobserved invariant characteristics that can usually influence self-perceived health (or other outcomes of health)

Comment: In my opinion that is a bad practice because your results apply only to the individuals included in the study, and do not extend beyond them. With individuals as random effects, you still control for the individual effects, but the residual variation includes the variation between individuals, as it should. But I won't say more because SO is not a statistics site.

Comment: I think what you are saying could be right. But the issue remains, especially that reviewers often ask for robustness checks using the average marginal effects with FE models. It is a pity that it is straightforward in Stata but it is much more complicated in R. Especially, that journals ask reproducible codes and then it would be nice to give the code using one software only.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think Stata computes the same kind of marginal effects, with equal weights on predictions. Please note that if you have a million fixed subjects, you have more than a million regression coefficients. that doesn't seem very robust to me, and certainly not parsimonious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried adjusting formula/datasets to get emmeans and plm to play nice.  Let me know if there's something here.  I realized the biglm answer wasn't going to cut it for a million individuals after some testing.

```
library(emmeans)
library(plm)
data("Males")  

## this runs but we need to get an equivalent result with expanded formula
## and expanded dataset
model_plm = plm(wage ~ exper + residence + health + residence*union,model = "within", index=c("nr"), data=Males)

## expanded dataset
Males2 <- data.frame(wage=Males[complete.cases(Males),"wage"],
                     model.matrix(wage ~ exper + residence + health + residence*union, Males), 
                     nr=Males[complete.cases(Males),"nr"])


(fmla2 <- as.formula(paste("wage ~ ", paste(names(coef(model_plm)), collapse= "+"))))

## expanded formula
model_plm2 <- plm(fmla2,
                  model = "within",
                  index=c("nr"), 
                  data=Males2)

(fmla2_rg <- as.formula(paste("wage ~ -1 +", paste(names(coef(model_plm)), collapse= "+"))))

plm2_rg <- qdrg(fmla2_rg,
                data = Males2,
                coef = coef(model_plm2),
                vcov = vcov(model_plm2),
                df = model_plm2$df.residual)

plm2_rg

### when all 3 residences are 0, that's `rural area`
### then just pick the rows when one of the residences are 1
emmeans(plm2_rg, c("residencenorth_east","residencenothern_central","residencesouth", "unionyes"))
```

Which gives, after some row-deletion:

```
> ### when all 3 residences are 0, that's `rural area`
> ### then just pick the rows when one of the residences are 1
> emmeans(plm2_rg, c("residencenorth_east","residencenothern_central","residencesouth", "unionyes"))
 residencenorth_east residencenothern_central residencesouth unionyes emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
                   0                        0              0        0 0.3777 0.0335 2677  0.31201    0.443
                   1                        0              0        0 0.3301 0.1636 2677  0.00929    0.651
                   0                        1              0        0 0.1924 0.1483 2677 -0.09834    0.483
                   0                        0              1        0 0.2596 0.1514 2677 -0.03732    0.557
                   0                        0              0        1 0.2875 0.1473 2677 -0.00144    0.576
                   1                        0              0        1 0.3845 0.1647 2677  0.06155    0.708
                   0                        1              0        1 0.3326 0.1539 2677  0.03091    0.634
                   0                        0              1        1 0.3411 0.1534 2677  0.04024    0.642

Results are averaged over the levels of: healthyes 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: I'm way behind the curve here, but what's wrong with `RG <- qdrg(~  -1 + exper + residence + health + residence*union, data = Males, coef = coef(model.plm), vcov = vcov(model.plm), df = df.residual(model.plm))`? This worked (i.e., didn't error) for me with a simpler example model. The index variable isn't part of the fixed effects so doesn't eat memory.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is what do we get from the expanded model & dataset? Just seems like we have all the stimates we need from the original model.

Comment: I learned that it's more complicated than my initial trial that didn't include factors. See the answer I added.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that when we add `-1` to the formula, that creates an extra column in the model matrix that is not included in the regression coefficients. (This is a byproduct of the way that R creates factor codings.)
So I can work around this by adding a strategically placed coefficient of zero. We also have to fix up the covariance matrix the same way:

```
library(emmeans)
library(plm)
data("Males")

mod <- plm(wage ~ exper + residence + health + residence*union,
           model = "within", 
           index = "nr", 
           data = Males)

BB <- c(coef(mod)[1], 0, coef(mod)[-1])
k <- length(BB)
VV <- matrix(0, nrow = k, ncol = k)
VV[c(1, 3:k), c(1, 3:k)] <- vcov(mod)

RG <- qdrg(~ -1 + exper + residence + health + residence*union, 
           data = Males, coef = BB, vcov = VV, df = df.residual(mod))
```

Verify that things line up:

```
> names(RG@bhat)
 [1] "exper"                             ""                                 
 [3] "residencenorth_east"               "residencenothern_central"         
 [5] "residencesouth"                    "healthyes"                        
 [7] "unionyes"                          "residencenorth_east:unionyes"     
 [9] "residencenothern_central:unionyes" "residencesouth:unionyes"
> colnames(RG@linfct)
 [1] "exper"                             "residencerural_area"              
 [3] "residencenorth_east"               "residencenothern_central"         
 [5] "residencesouth"                    "healthyes"                        
 [7] "unionyes"                          "residencenorth_east:unionyes"     
 [9] "residencenothern_central:unionyes" "residencesouth:unionyes"
```

They do line up, so we can get the results we need:

```
(EMM <- emmeans(RG, ~ residence * union))
 residence       union emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 rural_area      no     0.378 0.0335 2677  0.31201    0.443
 north_east      no     0.330 0.1636 2677  0.00929    0.651
 nothern_central no     0.192 0.1483 2677 -0.09834    0.483
 south           no     0.260 0.1514 2677 -0.03732    0.557
 rural_area      yes    0.287 0.1473 2677 -0.00144    0.576
 north_east      yes    0.385 0.1647 2677  0.06155    0.708
 nothern_central yes    0.333 0.1539 2677  0.03091    0.634
 south           yes    0.341 0.1534 2677  0.04024    0.642

Results are averaged over the levels of: health 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

In general, the key is to identify where the added column occurs. It's going to be the position of the first level of the first factor in the model formula. You can check it by looking at `names(coef(mod))` and `colnames(model.matrix(formula), data = data)` where `formula` is the model formula with intercept removed.

### Update: a general function

Here's a function that may be used to create a reference grid for any `plm` object. It turns out that sometimes these objects *do* have an intercept (e.g., random-effects models) so we have to check. For models lacking an intercept, you really should use this only for contrasts.

```
plmrg = function(object, ...) {
    form = formula(formula(object))
    if (!("(Intercept)" %in% names(coef(object))))
        form = update(form, ~ . - 1)
    data = eval(object$call$data, environment(form))
    mmat = model.matrix(form, data)
    sel = which(colnames(mmat) %in% names(coef(object)))
    k = ncol(mmat)
    b = rep(0, k)
    b[sel] = coef(object)
    v = matrix(0, nrow = k, ncol = k)
    v[sel, sel] = vcov(object)
    emmeans::qdrg(formula = form, data = data, 
        coef = b, vcov = v, df = df.residual(object), ...)
}
```

Test run:

```
> (rg = plmrg(mod, at = list(exper = c(3,6,9))))
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    exper = 3, 6, 9
    residence = rural_area, north_east, nothern_central, south
    health = no, yes
    union = no, yes

> emmeans(rg, "residence")
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
 residence       emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 rural_area       0.313 0.0791 2677   0.1579    0.468
 north_east       0.338 0.1625 2677   0.0190    0.656
 nothern_central  0.243 0.1494 2677  -0.0501    0.536
 south            0.281 0.1514 2677  -0.0161    0.578

Results are averaged over the levels of: exper, health, union 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: I was wondering whether you have an idea about the "NOTE:Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions". Is that something related to our discussion above?

Answer (score 1):

This potential solution uses `biglm::biglm()` to fit the lm model and then uses `emmeans::qdrg()` with a nuisance specified.   Does this approach help in your situation?

```
library(biglm)
library(emmeans)
## the biglm coefficients using factor() with all the `nr` levels has NAs.
## so restrict data to complete cases in the `biglm()` call
model_biglm <- biglm(wage ~ -1 +exper + residence+health + residence*union + factor(nr), data=Males[!is.na(Males$residence),])
summary(model_biglm)

## double check that biglm and lm give same/similar model
## summary(model_biglm)
## summary(model_lm)
summary(model_biglm)$rsq
summary(model_lm)$r.squared
identical(coef(model_biglm), coef(model_lm)) ## not identical!  but plot the coefficients...
head(cbind(coef(model_biglm), coef(model_lm)))
tail(cbind(coef(model_biglm), coef(model_lm)))
plot(cbind(coef(model_biglm), coef(model_lm))); abline(0,1,col="blue")


## do a "[q]uick and [d]irty [r]eference [g]rid and follow examples 
### from ?qdrg and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/FAQs.html 
  rg1 <- qdrg(wage ~ -1 + exper + residence+health + residence*union + factor(nr), 
              data = Males,
              coef = coef(model_biglm),
              vcov = vcov(model_biglm), 
              df = model_biglm$df.resid,
              nuisance="nr")
  
## Since we already specified nuisance in qdrg() we don't in emmeans():
  emmeans(rg1, c("residence","union"))
```

Which gives:

```
>   emmeans(rg1, c("residence","union"))
 residence       union emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 rural_area      no      1.72 0.1417 2677     1.44     2.00
 north_east      no      1.67 0.0616 2677     1.55     1.79
 nothern_central no      1.53 0.0397 2677     1.45     1.61
 south           no      1.60 0.0386 2677     1.52     1.68
 rural_area      yes     1.63 0.2011 2677     1.23     2.02
 north_east      yes     1.72 0.0651 2677     1.60     1.85
 nothern_central yes     1.67 0.0503 2677     1.57     1.77
 south           yes     1.68 0.0460 2677     1.59     1.77

Results are averaged over the levels of: 1 nuisance factors, health 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```